# Sleep function in php is causing my page to hang

Tags: php

I've been looking for hours for a solution to this problem.

I have a panel which takes everything in a given directory and displays it. I would like it to do this every 10 seconds because right now you have to refresh your entire page.

So when I do this

```
GetLogs(); sleep(5); GetLogs();
```

Instead of getting the directories, displaying them, waiting 5 seconds, and then displaying them again, it simply does GetLogs();, waits for 5 seconds then does it again, and then load my page. I have seen people use AJAX but it's a bit out of my league for this problem I think. I've read that changing my apache settings or php settings would resolve this problem but I have no idea how. I also looked into session_write_close and session_start but these do nothing, These functions are being called from within this php file. please help me!

I was stupid and for some reason thought I could use a server side language to sleep client-side, my bad. Could someone spoonfeed me an ajax call please?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what `sleep` does...

Comment: PHP is server side, it executes `GetLogs(); sleep(5); GetLogs();` on the server and when finished sends the results to the browser.

Comment: @JonStirling Really? So there's no way to let it "sleep" client-side?

Comment: Use a client side script like JS to make an AJAX call.

Comment: Sure, but that's not what you've asked about...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: @AbraCadaver I see, How would I go about doing this then? Should I use a javascript sleep function to call php functions?

Comment: While this question isn’t ideal in that it’s really the wrong question, I disagree with it being downvoted. This is a question that many new programmers are likely to ask. We can use this as an opportunity to guide them toward a better understanding of web technologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to refresh the page every 5 seconds you could use

```
<?php
header("Refresh: 5");
?>
```

This must be sent before any other output

Answer (score 0):

This question is a very common [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) asked by new developers.

PHP runs on the server.  The web browser has no knowledge of what's on the server.  To the web browser, the server is a black box: the web browser sends it text, the server does server stuff, and the server sends text back to the browser.  Typically the response text will describe a webpage in the form of HTML.  But the web browser has no way of knowing how that HTML was generated: it can't see the underlying PHP.

This process has a set order:

1. Web browser requests a web page
2. Server processes the request
3. Server responds with the HTML for a web page

You can't really change this order.  Technologies like ajax work around this by doing additional processing in the web browser and making additional requests.  This is handled by JavaScript.  For example:

1. Web browser requests a web page
2. PHP on the server processes the request
3. Server responds with the HTML for the web page
4. JavaScript embedded in the web page sets a timer for 10 seconds
5. After 10 seconds, the JavaScript requests the web page again
6. PHP on the server processes the request
7. Server responds with the HTML for the web page
8. JavaScript in the web browser receives the HTML and tells the browser to display it

This is a relatively simple exchange.  In practice, many web pages will get more complex.  For example, the server might respond with JSON instead of HTML; it will then be up to the JavaScript in the browser to do something useful with the JSON, such as generating HTML.

In your particular case, ideally the flow should look like this:

1. The web browser requests a web page.
2. The server responds with HTML.  This need not be handled by PHP; it could be a static .html file.
3. The HTML references a JavaScript file using a `<script>` tag.
4. The web browser sees the `<script>` tag in the HTML and requests it from the server.
5. The server sends the JavaScript file.
6. The web browser runs the JavaScript.
7. The JavaScript uses `setInterval` to run a JavaScript function every 10 seconds.
8. To ensure that the data is immediately available (without waiting 10 seconds), the JavaScript function is also called immediately.
9. Each time it runs, the JavaScript function uses ajax to request data from the server.
10. Each time the data is requested, PHP on the server runs.
11. PHP on the server obtains or calculates the latest data.
12. The PHP encodes the data with `json_encode()` instead of outputting HTML.
13. The server sends the JSON to the web browser.
14. The JavaScript function in the web browser receives the JSON.
15. Since the response is just text, the JavaScript has to parse the JSON using `JSON.parse()`.
16. The JavaScript processes the data and updates what's displayed in the user's web browser.

What's important to note here is that there isn't a fluent communication tunnel between the web browser and the server.  **You can't call a JavaScript function from PHP, and you can't call a PHP function from JavaScript.**  Each time one needs to send a message to the other:

1. It has to be initiated by the web browser.  The server can't arbitrarily send data to the web browser; the browser has to request it.  This means JavaScript can initiate an exchange, but PHP can't.
2. You're starting with a fresh run of the PHP script each time.  Nothing is saved.  All the variables are reset.  It's starting over at the beginning.

Think of it like this: Say there are two people, Alice and Bob.  Alice and Bob want to exchange messages.  The only way they can do that is via snail mail.  But Bob doesn't have any stamps.  So each time they want to exchange messages, Alice has to initiate the conversation.  She sends Bob a letter, including an extra stamp so Bob can send a response.  Bob has to wait for Alice's letter before he can send a response.  Once he responds, that's it--he can't edit the letter while it's in transit.  If he wants to make changes, he has to wait for Alice to request them.

*In the process of searching for an answer to your question, you may encounter instructions to disable buffering or refresh the page repeatedly.  While these may technically give the desired result in your particular case, they aren't really good solutions.  You should look into solving the actual issue at hand: you need to find a way to get ajax working with JavaScript in the web browser.*